# ActiveMQ starts to fail in Fuse Jboss when a feature is deployed

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-camel, fuseesb

Im having a problem when I deploy a feature. The feature contains three bundles, and Karaf deploys well these bundles, but when they are deployed ActiveMQ starts to having problems.

The deployed bundles are simples. The "complicated" is a camel route who expose a CXF endpoint and call a endpoint mock. I just attached to this threar the .kar, the zip of that kar and my fuse log. The service is running, but the problem with activeMQ happend always

The error is always the same:

```
2013-05-14 15:19:48,046 | INFO  | veMQ Broker: amq | ActiveMQServiceFactory$$anon$1   | ?                                   ? | 106 - org.springframework.context - 3.1.3.RELEASE | Refreshing org.fusesource.mq.fabric.ActiveMQServiceFactory$$anon$1@33c91e: startup date [Tue May 14 15:19:48 ART 2013]; root of context hierarchy
2013-05-14 15:19:48,048 | INFO  | veMQ Broker: amq | XBeanXmlBeanDefinitionReader     | ?                                   ? | 105 - org.springframework.beans - 3.1.3.RELEASE | Loading XML bean definitions from file [/home/ramiro/tecPlata/jboss-fuse-6.0.0.redhat-024/etc/activemq.xml]
2013-05-14 15:19:48,095 | INFO  | veMQ Broker: amq | DefaultListableBeanFactory       | ?                                   ? | 105 - org.springframework.beans - 3.1.3.RELEASE | Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1885c3a: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0]; root of factory hierarchy
2013-05-14 15:19:48,159 | INFO  | veMQ Broker: amq | PListStoreImpl                   | ?                                   ? | 114 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi - 5.8.0.redhat-60024 | PListStore:[/home/ramiro/tecPlata/jboss-fuse-6.0.0.redhat-024/data/amq/amq/tmp_storage] started
2013-05-14 15:19:48,163 | ERROR | veMQ Broker: amq | BrokerService                    | ?                                   ? | 114 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi - 5.8.0.redhat-60024 | Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ (amq, null). Reason: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=amq
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=amq
          at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:453)[:1.6.0_30]
          at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.internal_addObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1484)[:1.6.0_30]
          at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:963)[:1.6.0_30]
          at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:917)[:1.6.0_30]
          at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:312)[:1.6.0_30]
          at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:482)[:1.6.0_30]
          at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext.registerMBean(ManagementContext.java:380)[114:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.8.0.redhat-60024]
          at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.AnnotatedMBean.registerMBean(AnnotatedMBean.java:72)[114:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.8.0.redhat-60024]
          at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startManagementContext(BrokerService.java:2337)[114:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.8.0.redhat-60024]
          at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:543)[114:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.8.0.redhat-60024]
          at org.fusesource.mq.fabric.ActiveMQServiceFactory$ClusteredConfiguration$$anon$3.run(ActiveMQServiceFactory.scala:307)[128:org.jboss.amq.mq-fabric:6.0.0.redhat-024]
2013-05-14 15:19:48,164 | INFO  | veMQ Broker: amq | BrokerService                    | ?                                   ? | 114 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi - 5.8.0.redhat-60024 | Apache ActiveMQ 5.8.0.redhat-60024 (amq, null) is shutting down
2013-05-14 15:19:48,168 | INFO  | veMQ Broker: amq | TransportConnector               | ?                                   ? | 114 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi - 5.8.0.redhat-60024 | Connector openwire Stopped
2013-05-14 15:19:48,169 | INFO  | veMQ Broker: amq | PListStoreImpl                   | ?                                   ? | 114 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi - 5.8.0.redhat-60024 | PListStore:[/home/ramiro/tecPlata/jboss-fuse-6.0.0.redhat-024/data/amq/amq/tmp_storage] stopped
2013-05-14 15:19:48,169 | INFO  | veMQ Broker: amq | KahaDBStore                      | ?                                   ? | 114 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi - 5.8.0.redhat-60024 | Stopping async queue tasks
2013-05-14 15:19:48,169 | INFO  | veMQ Broker: amq | KahaDBStore                      | ?                                   ? | 114 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi - 5.8.0.redhat-60024 | Stopping async topic tasks
2013-05-14 15:19:48,169 | INFO  | veMQ Broker: amq | KahaDBStore                      | ?                                   ? | 114 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi - 5.8.0.redhat-60024 | Stopped KahaDB
2013-05-14 15:19:48,169 | INFO  | veMQ Broker: amq | BrokerService                    | ?                                   ? | 114 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi - 5.8.0.redhat-60024 | Apache ActiveMQ 5.8.0.redhat-60024 (amq, null) uptime 0.010 seconds
2013-05-14 15:19:48,169 | INFO  | veMQ Broker: amq | BrokerService                    | ?                                   ? | 114 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi - 5.8.0.redhat-60024 | Apache ActiveMQ 5.8.0.redhat-60024 (amq, null) is shutdown
2013-05-14 15:19:48,169 | INFO  | veMQ Broker: amq | ActiveMQServiceFactory           | ?                                   ? | 128 - org.jboss.amq.mq-fabric - 6.0.0.redhat-024 | Broker amq failed to start.  Will try again in 10 seconds
2013-05-14 15:19:48,169 | INFO  | veMQ Broker: amq | ActiveMQServiceFactory           | ?                                   ? | 128 - org.jboss.amq.mq-fabric - 6.0.0.redhat-024 | Exception on start: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=amq
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=amq
          at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:453)[:1.6.0_30]
          at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.internal_addObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1484)[:1.6.0_30]
          at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:963)[:1.6.0_30]
          at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:917)[:1.6.0_30]
          at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:312)[:1.6.0_30]
          at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:482)[:1.6.0_30]
          at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext.registerMBean(ManagementContext.java:380)[114:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.8.0.redhat-60024]
          at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.AnnotatedMBean.registerMBean(AnnotatedMBean.java:72)[114:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.8.0.redhat-60024]
          at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startManagementContext(BrokerService.java:2337)[114:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.8.0.redhat-60024]
          at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:543)[114:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.8.0.redhat-60024]
          at org.fusesource.mq.fabric.ActiveMQServiceFactory$ClusteredConfiguration$$anon$3.run(ActiveMQServiceFactory.scala:307)[128:org.jboss.amq.mq-fabric:6.0.0.redhat-024]
```

Dropbox URL to Fuse LOG https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/225304/fuse.log

Dropbox URL to .kar file https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/225304/PruebaFeature-1.0-SNAPSHOT.kar

This example I used a clean Fuse. Any ideas of what is happening? i dont know if the problem is the configuration of ActiveMQ, or anything else.

This is what i recive when I list activemq in Karaf

This is when I list the broker in karaf

```
JBossFuse:karaf@root> activemq:query --jmxlocal
Name = KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[/home/ramiro/tecPlata/jboss-fuse-6.0.0.redhat-024/data/amq/kahadb]
brokerName = amq
Transactions = []
Size = 13411
InstanceName = KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[/home/ramiro/tecPlata/jboss-fuse-6.0.0.redhat-024/data/amq/kahadb]
Data = [1]
type = Broker
Service = PersistenceAdapter

brokerName = amq
service = Health
CurrentStatus = Good
type = Broker

brokerName = amq
connector = clientConnectors
type = Broker
StatisticsEnabled = true
connectorName = openwire

destinationName = ActiveMQ.Advisory.MasterBroker
MemoryUsageByteCount = 0
DequeueCount = 0
type = Broker
destinationType = Topic
Name = ActiveMQ.Advisory.MasterBroker
MinEnqueueTime = 0
MaxAuditDepth = 2048
AverageEnqueueTime = 0.0
InFlightCount = 0
MemoryLimit = 67108864
brokerName = amq
EnqueueCount = 1
MaxEnqueueTime = 0
MemoryUsagePortion = 1.0
ProducerCount = 0
UseCache = true
BlockedProducerWarningInterval = 30000
AlwaysRetroactive = false
Options = 
MaxProducersToAudit = 64
PrioritizedMessages = false
ConsumerCount = 0
ProducerFlowControl = true
Subscriptions = []
QueueSize = 0
MaxPageSize = 200
DispatchCount = 0
MemoryPercentUsage = 0
ExpiredCount = 0

TopicSubscribers = []
TemporaryQueues = []
Uptime = 1 minute
TemporaryTopicSubscribers = []
MemoryPercentUsage = 0
BrokerVersion = 5.8.0.redhat-60024
StatisticsEnabled = true
TotalDequeueCount = 0
TopicProducers = []
QueueSubscribers = []
Topics = [org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=amq,destinationType=Topic,destinationName=ActiveMQ.Advisory.MasterBroker]
TotalMessageCount = 0
SslURL = 
TemporaryQueueSubscribers = []
BrokerName = amq
DynamicDestinationProducers = []
Persistent = true
DataDirectory = /home/ramiro/tecPlata/jboss-fuse-6.0.0.redhat-024/data/amq
Queues = []
DurableTopicSubscribers = []
TotalConsumerCount = 0
InactiveDurableTopicSubscribers = []
JobSchedulerStoreLimit = 0
TempPercentUsage = 0
MemoryLimit = 67108864
VMURL = vm://amq
OpenWireURL = tcp://fluxit-ntb-43:61616?maximumConnections=1000
JobSchedulerStorePercentUsage = 0
TotalEnqueueCount = 1
TemporaryQueueProducers = []
StompSslURL = 
TemporaryTopics = []
StompURL = 
Slave = false
BrokerId = ID:fluxit-ntb-43-58596-1368558172573-0:1
TotalProducerCount = 0
StorePercentUsage = 0
brokerName = amq
StoreLimit = 107374182400
TransportConnectors = {openwire=tcp://fluxit-ntb-43:61616?maximumConnections=1000}
TemporaryTopicProducers = []
TempLimit = 53687091200
QueueProducers = []
type = Broker
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The features.xml in your kar is incorrect which cause this error. It has some bundle like

```
<bundle>mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.configadmin/1.2.4</bundle>
<bundle>mvn:org.apache.aries/org.apache.aries.util/1.0.0</bundle>
<bundle>mvn:org.apache.aries.proxy/org.apache.aries.proxy.api/1.0.0</bundle>
<bundle>mvn:org.apache.aries.blueprint/org.apache.aries.blueprint/1.0.1.redhat-60024</bundle>
```

Those bundles are very fundamental for the  container and already get installed by container by default.

It shouldn't be in your features.xml, or if they're  there, you should have 
resolver="(obr)" for feature and dependency="true" for those bundle so that OBR resolver can kick in to prevent install redundant bundles.

Moreover, the

```
<bundle>mvn:org.apache.aries.blueprint/org.apache.aries.blueprint/1.0.1.redhat-60024</bundle>
```

is invalid for aries.blueprint 1.0.x, it should be

```
<bundle dependency="true" start-level="20">mvn:org.apache.aries.blueprint/org.apache.aries.blueprint.api/1.0.1.redhat-60024</bundle>
<bundle dependency="true" start-level="20">mvn:org.apache.aries.blueprint/org.apache.aries.blueprint.core/1.0.1.redhat-60024</bundle>
<bundle dependency="true" start-level="20">mvn:org.apache.aries.blueprint/org.apache.aries.blueprint.cm/1.0.1.redhat-60024</bundle>
```

instead. Otherwise you will see errors like

```
ERROR: Bundle org.apache.aries.blueprint [251] EventDispatcher: Error during dispatch. (java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.aries.blueprint.ext.impl.ExtNamespaceHandler cannot be cast to org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler)
```

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.aries.blueprint.ext.impl.ExtNamespaceHandler cannot be cast to org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler

This means you have two conflict aries.blueprint bundle installed in your container which messed up almost everything.

In a summary, change your features.xml in your kar like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<features>
  <feature name='tosMock' version='1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'>
    <bundle>mvn:com.tecplata.esb.services/tosMock/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</bundle>
  </feature>
  <feature name='esb-entities' version='1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'>
    <bundle>mvn:com.tecplata.esb/esb-entities/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</bundle>
  </feature>
  <feature name='vesselsService-sei' version='1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'>
  <feature version='1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'>esb-entities</feature>
    <bundle>mvn:com.tecplata.esb.services.sei/vesselsService-sei/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</bundle>
  </feature>
  <feature name='vesselsVisitorService' version='1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'>
    <bundle>mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.10.0.redhat-60024</bundle>
    <feature version='1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'>vesselsService-sei</feature>
    <bundle>mvn:com.tecplata.esb.services/vesselsVisitorService/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</bundle>
  </feature>
</features>
```

can make it work.
Freeman

Answer (score 0):

The user has cross posted the same questions in many places. When you do this please tell us, as the conversation is the scattered.

Being active discussed here:
http://fusesource.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=4797&tstart=0

But also posted here:
https://community.jboss.org/thread/228200